# Does urine, used topically, clear pimples?

Tags: natural-remedies, acne

Earlier today I heard some radio DJ's discussing some news story that brought up [urinating on a jellyfish sting](https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/q/1555/96). That led to a discussion about using "the first urine of the morning" to dab on acne in order to clear it up.

They wanted to know if anyone tried it and whether it worked. I thought it sounded strange since the only thing I could think of in urine that might possibly even remotely have an effect on pimples would be urea or uric acid.

Are there any studies that discuss this and actually shows if this is nonsense?

Comment: Sounds like a practical joke gone too far...

Comment: Given urine is deemed sterile (well, "mid-stream" urine anyway), it may have an effect no greater than washing would have. Still, interesting question +1